# How to draw a PNG in GDI+ and maintain transparency/alpha channel

Tags: c++, c, winapi, gdi+

Basically, the images with alpha draw correctly when draw directly on top of a solid colored surface, however when it hits a region where the window is transparent, the PNG with alpha values start having a white background.

Hopefully my code will help you guys decipher what is going on. All help is much appreciated.

**GDI+ Drawing**

```
Image indicator(L"resources\\images\\floating_icon [a] 1.png", FALSE);
g.DrawImage(&indicator, 0, 0);

TextureBrush myTextureBrush(&indicator);
g.FillRectangle(&myTextureBrush, WindowPadding, 50, WindowDim.right - WindowPadding * 2, WindowPadding);
```

**Window Properties**

```
hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_POPUP | WS_OVERLAPPED,
    0, 0, WindowDim.right, WindowDim.bottom, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, RGB(255, 255, 255), 0,
    LWA_COLORKEY);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your underlying bitmap is pure white (255,255,255) then when you draw an alpha image on top of that, you'll end up with a color that's not pure white (unless the pixel is completely transparent) - each pixel of the image is blended with the underlying color of the background.

The problem with this is that your color key is only going to make pure white pixels transparent, and anything else will be solid.

The solution would be to switch to using per-pixel alpha for your layered window.

Comment: How do I switch to per-pixel alpha for my layered window?

Comment: I know that you would use `UpdateLayeredWindow` but I am confused as to how to make UI changes to it since I won't call it in WM_PAINT. Basically, how do I call the function to repaint the screen if I use `UpdateLayeredWindow`?